# What is the issue with state being an array in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Started learning react but made my state as an array.
my state was not getting properly update when i did something like

`this.setState(state => [newItem, ...this.state])`

above statement was converting an array to integer indexed object

I was getting a warning

`index.js:2178 Warning: App.state: must be set to an object or null`

seems like there is some check in react-dom code like this

`if (state && (typeof state !== 'object' || isArray(state))) {`

[link](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/d328e362e86a6af4a0664e004b8f97f18ce972c8/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberClassComponent.js#L409)

why is this happening

**what are the issues i can face if i use the state as an array or something else than object or null**

Comment: If a library explicitly tells you `App.state: must be set to an object or null` it means that's all it can handle I would just stick to that.

Answer (score 2):

`setState` accepts objects, plain and simple. If you call `this.setState(['a','b'])` it will convert your array to an array-like object. Why? Because React allows that elsewhere in your code you should be able to call `this.setState({data: 'something'})` without having that fail. For reference `this.state` would now look like this:

```
{
  0: 'a',
  1: 'b',
  data: 'something'
}
```

Why did you get a warning? Because React performed this conversion, from array to array-like object, behind the scenes, and wants to let you know that things have changed. For example, after setting state to an array, you won't be able to call `this.state.map ...` or any other array methods.

If you need to store an array in state, set it to an object property: `this.setState({arrayData: ['a', 'b']})`. In general it's a good practice to wrap your data in object properties, because you will certainly be [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) as you develop your application.